# Validating SAML Assertion from SalesForce validator

Tags: java, saml, assertions, opensaml

I am Validating SAML Assertion from SalesForce validator. All my **Results** are OK. I am getting warning at point 12 as in figure.

[image]

How can I validate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a proper XML digital signature on your SAML object.  Please see: https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/OSTwoUserManJavaDSIG

Comment: You are right. Tell me  1) what data I need in order to create proper XML digital signature.  2)Can I create proper XML digital signature without code using hard coded values and validate it at SalesForce validator?

Comment: You need a certificate and private signing key.  You should create these on your side, not from SFDC itself.  Hardcoded values is difficult.  A signature proves integrity & authenticity so must be calculated based on the data you are signing.  Without signatures, SAML has very little security - so it is vital it is done properly.